# Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surface given in spherical coordinates by $R = 4-3\cos(\phi)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates

It is worth noting that $R$ in this case denotes the distance from origin to a point $P$ in space. You may be more familiar with $\rho$ instead of $R$.

Here is my attempted solution:

I am assuming that since $0\le\phi\le \pi$  this can be exploited to find a similar range for $R$, as $R=4-3\cos(\phi)$. Doing this I find that $1\le R\le 7$. This thus allows me to set up the following triple integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_1^7R\cdot R^2\sin(\phi)\, \mathrm{d}R\, \mathrm{d}\phi\, \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

However, this gives me an incorrect answer. Can anyone here identify which assumption I have made that is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Please see if my transcription is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up an integral for a spherical shell, not an elliptical surface.  The radius depends on $\phi$, so that needs to be reflected in the limits.

Reverse order of integration from what is usually presented to get

$$2 \pi \int_0^{\pi} d\phi \, \sin{\phi} \, \int_0^{4-3 \cos{\phi}} dR \, R^2$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{2 \pi}{3} \int_0^{\pi} d\phi \, \sin{\phi} \, (4-3 \cos{\phi})^3 = \frac{2 \pi}{3} \int_{-1}^1 du \, (4-3 u)^3$$

The last integral is easily evaluated; I get $6536 \pi$.